# Pyqt5 Find row of QlistWidgetItem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a custom widget which has a button that is associated with it. Is there a way to that when the button on the custom widget is clicked that I can find out what row that current custom widget is on in the QListWidget?

Files

Main_GUI.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(353, 237)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 353, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add Item"))
```

CustomWidget_GUI.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Table_Widget_Insert(object):
    def setupUi(self, Table_Widget_Insert):
        Table_Widget_Insert.setObjectName("Table_Widget_Insert")
        Table_Widget_Insert.resize(278, 66)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(Table_Widget_Insert)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Table_Widget_Insert)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(Table_Widget_Insert)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Table_Widget_Insert)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.retranslateUi(Table_Widget_Insert)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Table_Widget_Insert)

    def retranslateUi(self, Table_Widget_Insert):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Table_Widget_Insert.setWindowTitle(_translate("Table_Widget_Insert", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Table_Widget_Insert", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Table_Widget_Insert", "Row Number"))
```

CustomWidget.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from CustomWidget_GUI import *


class SignalsObject(QObject):
    listWidgetCurrentIndex = pyqtSignal(str)

class CustomListEntry(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.CustomUi = Ui_Table_Widget_Insert()
        self.CustomUi.setupUi(self)
        self.setUpMainUiFunction()
        self.signals = SignalsObject()

    def setUpMainUiFunction(self):
        self.CustomUi.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.rowNumber)

    def setlabel(self,label):
        self.CustomUi.label.setText(label)

    def setButtonName(self,name):
        self.CustomUi.pushButton.setObjectName(name)

    def rowNumber(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        name = sender.objectName().split("__")
        entryNumber = name[1]

        self.signals.listWidgetCurrentIndex.emit(entryNumber)
```

Main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from Main_GUI import *

from CustomWidget import *




class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.MainUi = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.MainUi.setupUi(self)
        self.setUpMainUiFunction()
        self.listEntryNumber = 0


    def setUpMainUiFunction(self):
        self.MainUi.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.addCustomEntry)


    def addCustomEntry(self):
        self.listEntryNumber = self.listEntryNumber + 1

        CustomWidget = CustomListEntry()
        CustomWidget.setObjectName("entry"+str(self.listEntryNumber))

        CustomWidget.setlabel("Entry Number= "+str(self.listEntryNumber))

        CustomWidget.signals.listWidgetCurrentIndex.connect(self.findListIndex)

        CustomWidget.setButtonName("button__"+ str(self.listEntryNumber))

        myQListWidgetItem = QListWidgetItem(self.MainUi.listWidget)
            #pdb.set_trace()
        myQListWidgetItem.setSizeHint(CustomWidget.sizeHint())

        self.MainUi.listWidget.addItem(myQListWidgetItem)
        self.MainUi.listWidget.setItemWidget(myQListWidgetItem, CustomWidget)

    def findListIndex(self,entryNumber):
        print(entryNumber)
        # items = self.MainUi.feederSchedule_listWidget.findItems("entry"+entryNumber,Qt.MatchExactly)
        items = self.MainUi.listWidget.findChildren(CustomListEntry,"entry"+entryNumber)
        # item = self.MainUi.feederSchedule_listWidget.findItems(items, Qt.MatchRegExp)
        if len(items) > 0:
            for item in items:
                print ("row number of found item =",self.MainUi.listWidget.row(item))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I can see that it is able to find all of the items in the `QListWidget` but I can't seem to be able to match my custom object with one of those that are listed. This is where I am getting stuck with being able to find the row. Also in my actual program I will be deleting row. the entry number must be seperate from the row number

Comment: @eyllanesc I have edited it to provided a minimal example of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Hi, so you need to get the entry number, regardless of the position in the table, or the current row number regardless of the entry number, e.g. if you delete entry number 2, then entry number 3 will still be entry number 3 but the row number will be 2?

Comment: @Isma I would like to get the row number regardless of the entry number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it is best to implement a custom QListWidget that allows you to obtain the row, the widget should not know which row it belongs to but the listwidget should know it.

So I'll create the following is the custom QListWidget that emits the clicked_widget signal indicating the row number of the widget that emits the clicked signal:

**clickablelistwidget.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class ClickableListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    clicked_widget = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def append_widget(self, widget_clickable):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.addItem(item)
        item.setSizeHint(widget_clickable.sizeHint())
        self.setItemWidget(item, widget_clickable)
        if hasattr(widget_clickable, "clicked"):
            if isinstance(widget_clickable.clicked, QtCore.pyqtBoundSignal):
                widget_clickable.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        widget = self.sender()
        gp = widget.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint())
        lp = self.viewport().mapFromGlobal(gp)
        item = self.itemAt(lp)
        row = self.row(item)
        self.clicked_widget.emit(row)
```

Then modify the Main_GUI.py file to replace the QListWidget with the new class:

**Main_GUI.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from clickablelistwidget import ClickableListWidget

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(353, 237)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.listWidget = ClickableListWidget(self.centralwidget) # <---
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 353, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add Item"))
```

Your custom widget is modified so that it emits the clicked signal when the button is pressed:

**CustomWidget.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from CustomWidget_GUI import Ui_Table_Widget_Insert

class CustomListEntry(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Table_Widget_Insert):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomListEntry, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setUpMainUiFunction()

    def setUpMainUiFunction(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

    def setlabel(self,label):
        self.label.setText(label)
```

Now it can be used in the main file:

**Main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from Main_GUI import Ui_MainWindow
from CustomWidget import CustomListEntry

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setUpMainUiFunction()

    def setUpMainUiFunction(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.addCustomEntry)
        self.listWidget.clicked_widget.connect(self.on_clicked_widget)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def addCustomEntry(self):
        listEntryNumber = self.listWidget.count()
        custom_widget = CustomListEntry()
        custom_widget.setlabel("Entry Number= {}".format(listEntryNumber))
        self.listWidget.append_widget(custom_widget)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_clicked_widget(self, row):
        print("row number of found item = {}".format(row))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

At the end your folder must have the following structure:

```
├── clickablelistwidget.py
├── CustomListWidget.py
├── CustomWidget_GUI.py
├── CustomWidget.py
├── Main_GUI.py
└── Main.py
```

---

This method has the advantage that it uncouples classes making it easily reusable. You do not have to resort to the objectName or inject the QListWidgetItem to the widget that could be tedious if we have many types of widgets. :-).

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you